# Python for loop single liner for concatenating 2 strings

Tags: python-2.7

I have to implement below pseudo code in python.

```
dict = {}
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [2,4,5,7,8]
dict['msg'] = "List 2 items not in list 1 : "

for x in list 2:
   if x in list1:
      dict['msg'] += x

<write in log : dict['msg']>
```

If I use value of msg as list

```
dict['msg'] = ["List 2 items not in list 1 : "]
```

I can append the values in single liner as

```
[dict['msg'].append(x) for x in L2 if x not in L1]
```

but then the result on output page will be as

```
msg : [
     "List 2 items not in list 1 :",
       7,
       8
      ]
```

I want result in single line as

```
msg : List 2 items not in list 1 : 7,8
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are trying to use a dict here in the first place. Did the same with a string and list. While printing I convert the list to string.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [2,4,5,7,8]
msg = "List 2 items not in list 1 : "
exclusion = [ str(i) for i in list2 if i not in list1 ]
print msg, ', '.join(x)
```

Output:

> List 2 items not in list 1 :  7, 8

---

With dict:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [2,4,5,7,8]
d['msg'] = "List 2 items not in list 1 : "
d['msg'] = [ str(i) for i in list2 if i not in list1 ]
print d['msg']
```

Output:

> 'List 2 items not in list 1 : 7, 8'